# Data layers in REST service

Tags: c#, json, database, rest

I am wondering on how to design a `REST` service so that my **Data Access Layer** (Persistence layer that talks to the database) and my **"Business" entities** are well separated. By "Business" entities I mean the very objects that are returned to the client, for example as JSONs.

The main thing is that the database doesn't support all the fancy types such as `enums` which are supported in any OO language. Instead, the database works with plain `strings` and `ints` etc. The same thing is on the other side with the JSONs. You only get the primitives deserializing it.

Now, let's say that my data model ("business" entity) is defined like this:

***Employee.cs***

```
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string BirthPlace { get; set; }

    public EmployeeGender Gender { get; set; }

    public string OIB { get; set; }

    public string CurrentPlace { get; set; }

    public DepartmentCode Department { get; set; }
```

Here, the `DepartmentCode` and `EmployeeGender` are both enums. For example:

***DepartmentCode.cs***

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum DepartmentCode
{
    UNKNOWN,
    D_21510,
    D_21520,
    D_21540,
    D_21570,
    D_SLFIN,
    D_SLKPO
}
```

However, in the database, `Gender` is defined as an `int`. The idea is to have 0 for male, 1 for female, and 2 for undefined. Similarly, the `DepartmentCode` is defined as a string (`VARCHAR`).

Now, my idea was to have another data model that would type-correspond to the database, meaning that it would no longer have those `enums`, but would have directly `strings` and `ints`. Something like the following:

***EmployeeDb.cs***

```
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string BirthPlace { get; set; }

    public int Gender { get; set; }

    public string OIB { get; set; }

    public string CurrentPlace { get; set; }

    public string Department { get; set; }
```

The reason why I am using enums in the first place, is that I want to avoid some "garbage" values floating around my service. But enums are extremely non-practical to use with the database, and there has to be a place in the code where the conversion happens.

Generally, my question is **where** should this conversion happen. And more importantly, does it make any sense to define my service API with "complex" models that have those enums, or I should stick to normal string and int fields?

The communications goes like: `JSON -- data model (layers?) -- database`. Here, both the `JSON` and `Database` use very primitive types, while in my code I would like to have some more complex logic. So the conversion should probably be done twice. Once in the GET request: from database to JSON. Once in the POST request: from JSON to the database.

How are such things usually designed? In terms of how the API is defined, and how is then defined the conversion database-API?

Comment: i don't know what database you are using that in 2017 does not have enum, maybe you should change it to postgres where you can create your own data types https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html

Answer (score 0):

Between your application and your database, you are dealing with mapping your logical data model to your physical data model. This is often done using frameworks like Entity Framework or NHibernate. They are ORM-frameworks. You can also do it yourself, of course.

As for the relation between your business logic and your service interfaces, have a look at Data Transfer Objects, or DTO's. They are a common way to communicate data between services in the form of flattened or simplified forms of your actual classes. Mapping to and from them can be done using hand-written mapping methods or using tools like Automapper.